# How to keep many variables equal without assigning to them all every time?

Tags: python, variables, variable-assignment

What I'm trying to do is keeping the three variables equal without assigning them every time.

```
a=b=c=4
b=10
print a,b,c # 4 10 4
```

or in other words if I have many variables, if one of them changes, how to make the other variables change too?

```
print a # a=10
print b # b=10 
print c # c=10
```

How to keep many variables equal in the whole code?
I know that I can easily reassign them.
Is there any better way than this or or do I have to assign all the variables every time?

Comment: If they are always equal, why do they all have an independent existence?

Comment: You could make `a` a list of one element. i.e. `a = [0]`. After doing that, `b=c=a` would result in all of them referring to the (mutable) list that `a` refers to. If you then change `a` with something like `a[0] = 42`, the both `b[0]` and `c[0]` will refer to the current value of its first (and only) element in that list.

Comment: sure i have considered that but in some cases i prefer to use different variables names in order to make the code easily when i want to read it again

Comment: Having variables linked like this IMO makes the code *less* readable.  I guarantee you'll forget arbitrary dependencies

Comment: @martineau i liked this solution very much

Comment: @martineau but i want to make the code easy to read because if two persons ( ex : mark and john ) take the same salary every month if salary = mark_sal = john_sal
salary = 1000 it will help me a lot in writing the next lines

Comment: @user3483203  can you explain it with any example please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an object-oriented way that formalizes the suggestion I made in a comment — which was basically to put the shared object inside a mutable container, like a list.

```
from __future__ import print_function

class Mutable(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = [value]

    def get_value(self):
        return self._value[0]

    def set_value(self, value):
        self._value[0] = value

    value = property(get_value, set_value)

    def __repr__(self):
         return repr(self.get_value())

class Pointer(Mutable):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        if not isinstance(obj, (Mutable, Pointer)):
            raise ValueError(
                "{!r} is not a object of type Mutable or Pointer".format(obj))
        self._value = obj._value


if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = Mutable(0)
    b = Pointer(a)
    c = Pointer(b)
    print(a, b, c)  # -> 0 0 0
    a.value = 13
    print(a, b, c)  # -> 13 13 13
    b.value = 42
    print(a, b, c)  # -> 42 42 42
```